# New to Python, need some direction on checking user input against a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was messing around and wanted to see if I could get this simple program to work. I want to check the user input against my list and output whether or not it is in the list.  How I have it setup up currently it will return for the 0 index but not the other two.  What am I doing wrong?

```
print("Check to See if You are Registered:")
name = input("Please Enter Your Name:")
check_name = ["lisa", "jim", "betty"]

if name == check_name[0]:
   print("Welcome lisa")

   if name == check_name[1]:
      print("Welcome jim")

   elif name == check_name[2]:
        print("Welcome betty")

   pass

else:
    print("Sorry, Looks like you are not in the system")

pass
```

Comment: Indentation is important in Python.

Comment: Please choose a meaningful title

Comment: Also, don't use unnecessary `pass` statements in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your last two `if` statements are only evaluating nested inside of the first one. You need to unindent them so that they'll evaluate if the first does not.

Another solution:

```
print("Check to See if You are Registered:")
name = input("Please Enter Your Name:")
check_name = ["lisa", "jim", "betty"]
if name not in check_name:
    print("Sorry, Looks like you are not in the system")
```

Comment: What about welcoming the people whose name is there in the list? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation problem.

```
print("Check to See if You are Registered:")
name = input("Please Enter Your Name:")
check_name = ["lisa", "jim", "betty"]

if name == check_name[0]:
    print("Welcome lisa")

elif name == check_name[1]:
    print("Welcome Jim")

elif name == check_name[2]:
    print("Welcome Betty")

else:
    print("Sorry, Looks like you are not in the system")
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got your answer above. Here is an alternate solution negating the need of multiple `if` statements making your code concise:

```
print("Check to See if You are Registered:")
name = input("Please Enter Your Name:")
check_name = ["lisa", "jim", "betty"]

if name in check_name:
    print("Welcome %s" %name)
else:
    print("Sorry, Looks like you are not in the system")
```

The command `if name in check_name:` checks if the input name exists in the name list and welcomes the corresponding person. If the input name doesn't exist, it throws the `Sorry...` statement

Comment: Thanks! I just got started with this language and haven't came across this process yet.  I kind of figured I was going the long way about it.

Comment: That's why I always try to provide alternate solutions. This way I get to know other people's solution and share mine with them